# grpc proto file parser

Tags: python, parsing, protocol-buffers

I want to parse a .proto file that is part of a gRPC client/server definition.  I just want a starting point for doing this.  I have the gRPC code installed and can autogenerate python code from the proto files.  I am wondering if there are any obvious python classes in the gRPC code (or open source libs out there) that read in proto files and, in some limited way, parses them into some kind of structured objects?

Answer (score 2):

[parsy](https://github.com/python-parsy/parsy) (combinator library) has an example that parses `.proto` files, version 3. You can find it  in the [repo](https://github.com/python-parsy/parsy/blob/8f091eb053cecb2f4f4c737ab2b7cff1362a28b4/examples/proto3.py). The result is a structured object, using simple custom defined classes such as `Proto` for the whole file, which has a `statements` attribute, which contains `Import` for each import line, `Message` for each message etc.

Comment: Note: The docs and repo links in this answer are no longer functional.
Here is a working link for the [repo](https://github.com/python-parsy/parsy/blob/8f091eb053cecb2f4f4c737ab2b7cff1362a28b4/examples/proto3.py)

Answer (score 1):

The gRPC web page tells me that it uses protobufs syntax as its IDL. The examples directory included with the pyparsing source distribution includes a pure Python protobuf parser. You can view it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/examples/protobuf_parser.py